# Problemas com NETBEANS e Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

Bom dia Pessoal, tudo bem? , estou tentando realizar um projeto com jpa e mysql mas todas as vezes que vai salvar as informações no BD da um erro, alguém consegue me ajudar estou a dias tentando resolver e não consigo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já realizei vario procedimentos encontrados na internet e até agora nada, adicionei o conector J nas bibliotecas, revi o persistence.xml e tudo mais!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: No caso estou criando um projeto com a AP JPA, e todas as vezes que vou rodar o codigo para criar as informações na tabela do BD ele apresenta o erro na foto acima

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas não pq nesse arquivo ele seta por uma class main o meu está no persistence.xml

Comment: então adicione mais detalhes na pergunta André, como está não se sabe nem com faz a conexão, se não tem erro no código, etc. Adicione mais detalhes para podermos ajudar